# Why do I not get redirected to /login when accessing a secure page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, es6-promise, react-admin

I am recreating the issue as I am not sure if that's a bug and a previous issue created for this just disappeared =/

### Description

During an upgrade from `react-admin` v2 to v3.3.0, I encounter issue to get redirected to `/login` after rewriting the `authProvider`

- react-admin [documentation](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Authentication.html) | [github](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin)

My `authProvider.js` contains the following methods:

```
export default function createAuthProvider(urls, client, options) {
  return {
    login: (params) =>  {
      return fetchLoginBatch(params, urls, client, options);
    },
    logout: (params) => params.jwt ? fetchLogout(makeRequestLogout(urls.logout, params.jwt), options) : Promise.resolve(),
    checkError: (error) => {
      const { status } = error;
      if (status === 401 || status === 403) {
        return Promise.reject();
      }
      return Promise.resolve();
    },
    checkAuth: (params) => params.jwt ? Promise.resolve() : Promise.reject(),
    getPermissions: (params) => params.jwt ? Promise.resolve(params.jwt.authorities) : Promise.resolve(),
    refreshJwt: (params) => params.jwt ? fetchRefreshJwt(makeRefreshJwtRequest(client.accessTokenUri, {
      grant_type: 'refresh_token',
      refresh_token: params.jwt.refresh_token,
    }, client), options) : Promise.resolve()
  };
}
```

It is as described in [documentation](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Authentication.html) and [example](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/master/examples/simple/src/authProvider.js)

### Expected

I expect to be redirected to `/login`.

### Result

Instead, I stay on the page, `checkAuth` is well called and the `jwt` is `null`,

[image]

### Possible fix

It is offered to change the redirect using an argument to rejected promise:

```
    checkAuth: () => localStorage.getItem('token')
        ? Promise.resolve()
        : Promise.reject({ redirectTo: '/no-access' }),
```

But adding `Promise.reject({ redirectTo: '/login' })` doesn't help even if the code run.

I have tried to add some logging in `ra-core/lib/sideEffect/auth.js`:

```
console.log('auth');

exports.handleCheck = function (authProvider) {
    console.log('handleCheck', authProvider);

    return function (action) {
        console.log('action', action);

        var payload, meta, error_1, redirectTo, errorMessage;

        console.log('redirectTo', redirectTo, 'meta', meta);
```

`handleCheck` is called but never `action`, it seems that the saga is ignored somehow.

### Question

- How should client side handle `permissions` and `checkAuth` rejection params ?
- What should I check next to see why the redirection is failing?

How does the `ra-core` code follow?

Comment: There might be a "typo". Let me just post a line that might be causing the trouble.

Comment: As a matter of fact, you might want to check your logic across all your `itenary` operators. You might face more challenges regards permissions, logout etc.

Comment: What do you mean `itenary` operators ?

Comment: Nice catch, too. Meant the `ternary` operator:)

Comment: Hi, without fetchLoginBatch() content, it's not clear what you're doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you kindly scrutinize this line?

```js
// authProvider.js

// checking if request has a JWT (this might be a typo!)
-  checkAuth: (params) => params.jwt ? Promise.resolve() : Promise.resolve(),

// If not, we should reject thus triggering a redirect.
+  checkAuth: (params) => params.jwt ? Promise.resolve() : Promise.reject(),
```

Let me know how it works out.

Comment: Hi @MwamiTovi, nice catch, unfortunately it was me doing a test trying to set if the test was wrong, I fixed it in my question.

Comment: OK, great. Let me scrutinize the snippets more and see what's happening in there.

Comment: I was wrong, I used to test it, it use to not work, but then I retested it, and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of authProvider, it works with both React-Admin 2 and React-Admin 3.3.1

Using:

```
<Admin authProvider={authProvider(loginUrl, logoutUrl)} ...>

import storage from './storage'
import {
  AUTH_LOGIN,
  AUTH_LOGOUT,
  AUTH_ERROR,
  AUTH_CHECK,
  AUTH_GET_PERMISSIONS
} from 'react-admin'

import {
  LB_TOKEN,
  getTokenId
} from './token'

export const authProvider = (loginApiUrl, logoutApiUrl, noAccessPage = '/login') => {
  return (type, params) => {
    if (type === AUTH_LOGIN) {
      const request = new Request(loginApiUrl, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(params),
        headers: new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }),
      })

      return fetch(request)
        .then(response => {
          if (response.status < 200 || response.status >= 300) {
            throw new Error(response.statusText)
          }
          return response.json()
        })
        .then(({ ttl, ...data }) => {
          storage.save(LB_TOKEN, data, ttl)
          return Promise.resolve(data) 
        })
    }

    if (type === AUTH_LOGOUT) {
      const token = getTokenId()
      if (token) {
        storage.remove(LB_TOKEN) 

        if (logoutApiUrl) { 
          const request = new Request(`${logoutApiUrl}?access_token=${token}`, { 
            method: 'POST',
            headers: new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'}),
          })

          return fetch(request)
            .then(response => {
              if (response.status !== 204) {
                console.error('authProvider - Logout, status:', response) 
              }
              return Promise.resolve() 
            })
        }
      }
      return Promise.resolve()
    }

    if (type === AUTH_ERROR) {
      const { status } = params 

      if (status === 401 || status === 403) {
        storage.remove(LB_TOKEN)
        return Promise.reject()
      }
      return Promise.resolve()
    }

    if (type === AUTH_CHECK) { 
      const token = storage.load(LB_TOKEN)

      if (token && token.id) {
        return Promise.resolve()
      } else {
        storage.remove(LB_TOKEN) 
        return Promise.reject({ redirectTo: noAccessPage })
      }
    }

    if (type === AUTH_GET_PERMISSIONS) {
      const token = storage.load(LB_TOKEN)

      if (token && token.user && token.user.roleId) {
        return Promise.resolve(token.user.roleId)
      } else {
        console.warn('Unknown user rights:', token)
        storage.remove(LB_TOKEN) 
        return Promise.reject({ redirectTo: noAccessPage }) 
      }
    }

    return Promise.reject(`authProvider - Unknown method, type: ${type}, params: ${params}`)
  }
}
```

Comment: Write when you find what was missing in your implementation.

Comment: I am unsure, because I didn't change anything and it started to work. I have played with a bunch of thing like webpack resolve alias, so maybe it was it, maybe it was the combination of this and @MwamiTovi answwer